# Laravel 5.4 - Checking data from another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Still quite confused on laravel 5.4 as I am new to it, I am trying to get the row of data from the **Record** table who got the same *year* and *course* with the *user*.

```
$show = Profile::where('userid','=',$id)->first();
$check1 = Record::where([['year','=',$show->year],['course','=',$show->course]])->get();
```

It was successfully running and was able to get the list of people. Now, what I wanted to do next is to check if those list of people (results from *$check1*) exist on another table called **Fbuser**. Tried doing this,

```
$check2 = Fbuser::where([['first_name','=',$check1->firstname],['last_name','=',$check1->lastname]]);
    if ($check2 === null) {
        return 'recommend';
    } else {
        return 'exit';
    }
```

But it gave me an error

> (1/1) Exception
>   Property [firstname] does not exist on this collection instance.

Is there any way that I can go around about this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is table Fbuser fields name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check1` contains a collection of records not a single `Record`. To get a single `Record` you can use foreach. Try this:

```
foreach($check1 as $record){
    $check2 = Fbuser::where([['first_name','=',$record->firstname],['last_name','=',$record->lastname]]);
    if ($check2 === null) {
        return 'recommend';
    } else {
        return 'exit';
    }
}
```

You also should get results for `$check2`. `where()` retuns query builder object. You should use `get()` or `first()` at the end to get results for this query.

```
$check2 = Fbuser::where([['first_name','=',$check1->firstname],['last_name','=',$check1->lastname]])->get()
```

Comment: Oh right. Haven't thought about that. Thanks sir. Tho I'm not sure if I'm getting the right results but is there any way I could get the list of people just to check if its the right list.

Comment: Ah I've tried dd(), suppose to be giving me 2 results but its only giving me one. Think something's wrong with my query but thanks sir , It's working now.

Comment: @user1540 you should also fix your query for `check2`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Weird, it's not giving me results anymore

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `get()` you get a collection. You could just get one of objects by it's index, like

```
{{ $collection[0]->name }}
```

Modify this :

```
$show = Profile::where('userid','=',$id)->first();
$check1 = Record::where([['year','=',$show->year],['course','=',$show->course]])->get();

$check2 = Fbuser::where([['first_name','=',$check1[0]->firstname], ['last_name','=',$check1[0]->lastname]]);
if ($check2 === null) {
    return 'recommend';
} else {
    return 'exit';
}
```

Hope it helps.